# Why my SOAP envelope request has backslash ("\") character in it?

Tags: cxf, soap-client, ibm-datapower, envelope

I'm working on a SOAP based web service (JAX-WS, Apache CXF). In my SOAP request, there is backslash ("\") in every element which starts with http. For instance :-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="**\**http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/**\**"
soap:encodingStyle="**\**http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding**\**">
```

I tried a lot to figured out this issue. As per my understanding, my Java code is not putting this character ("\") anywhere in the entire SOAP envelope request. But from where this character is coming?

Q1) Even if SOAP envelope request has this backslash ("\"), then does it mean it is an invalid request or still a valid SOAP based web service request.

Q2) Any idea how it is getting generated, is it at client side (Java Stub) or at the host side? Is it because of any specific logging pattern? I'm running behind IBM DataPower, is it because of that?

Q3) How to get rid of it? Any change at client-side or at web service host (SOA) side?

Please assist to clear my queries.

Thank you